# Finding a square root of a power series in terms of another power series

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, power-series

I want to find a square root of a power series in the following way:

Let $$A(x)=a_0+a_1x+\cdots=\sum_{j\ge 0}a_jx^j\qquad \mathrm{and}\qquad B(x)=b_0+b_1x+\ldots=\sum_{i\ge 0}b_ix^i$$
such that $a_0>0$ and $b_0>0$ and $A=B^2$.

How can I express the coefficients $a_j$ in terms of $b_i$? I used the Cauchy product to get $a_j=\sum_{k=0}^jb_kb_{j-k}$, but have no idea how to continue.

Can someone help me out with finding a recursive relation between $a_j$ and $b_i$ with initial value for the sequence $(b_i)$?

Comment: You just did that. Do you want $b$ in terms of $a$?

Comment: As you investigated it will be a self-convolution of the $b_j$s. You can also do it by a discrete fourier transform of coefficients and take roots and inverse transform.

Answer (score 6):

From the Cauchy product, identify the coefficients by increasing powers.

$$b_0^2=a_0,\\
2b_0b_1=a_1,\\
2b_0b_2+b_1^2=a_2,\\
2b_0b_3+2b_1b_2=a_3,\\
2b_0b_4+2b_1b_3+b_2^2=a_4,\\
\cdots$$

Then
$$b_0=\sqrt{a_0},\\
b_1=\frac{a_1}{2b_0},\\
b_2=\frac{a_2-b_1^2}{2b_0},\\
b_3=\frac{a_3-2b_1b_2}{2b_0},\\
b_4=\frac{a_4-b_2^2-2b_1b_3}{2b_0},\\
\cdots$$

Answer (score 3):

There is no *known* **closed form** of $\{b_k\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ in terms of $\{a_k\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ **in general**.

Some particular cases are remarkable.

- For $x \in \mathbb{R}$, we have $A=B^2$, with $$
     A=e^x=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k!},\quad
     B=\sqrt{e^x}=e^{\large\frac{x}2}
     = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{2^k k!}. \tag1$$
- For $|x|<1$, we have $A=B^2$, with $$ A=1+x,\quad
     B=\sqrt{1+x}=(1+x)^{1/2}
     = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{1/2}{k}x^k \tag2$$ and generally, for $|x|<1$,  $$ A=(1+x)^{2\alpha},\quad B=(1+x)^{\alpha}
     = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{\alpha}{k}x^k \tag3$$ where   $$ \binom{\alpha}{k}:=\frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)\ldots(\alpha-k+1)}{k!},\quad
     \alpha \in \mathbb{R}. \tag4$$

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking for is a special case of [Faa di Bruno's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula), which is a formula expressing the Taylor coefficients of the composition $f(g(x))$ of two functions in terms of the coefficients of the individual functions $f(t)$ and of $g(x)$. Your question is simply about the case where $f(t)=\sqrt{t}$, so just plug in that function into the formula.

Note that Faa di Bruno's formula is fairly complicated -- the $n$th coefficient of $f(g(x))$ is expressed as a sum over the $p(n)$ [integer partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) of $n$. Since the number of partitions grows [exponentially in $\sqrt{n}$](http://www.theoremoftheday.org/NumberTheory/Partitions/TotDPartitions.pdf), that can mean a lot of terms to process even for $n$ that's moderately large.

Answer (score 1):

We can also use the **convolution theorem** in Fourier analysis $$\widehat{f*g} = \hat f \cdot \hat g,$$ where $*$ denotes  convolution and $\cdot$ is the ordinary  product.

We can do this because the product of any polynomial or power series corresponds to a discrete convolution of it's coefficients so it becomes a product once we step over into the Fourier domain.

Now what remains to solve $x^2 = c$ in the Fourier domain (for each Fourier coefficient). The trivial solution would just be to choose the same $x = \sqrt{c}$ for some suitable branch of the complex root function. And then lastly to perform the inverse-transform.